# Error en javascript 404

Tags: javascript, error404

Tengo este error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

En este renglón:

```
<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"> 
</script>
```

Lo que pasa es que el archivo *jQuery-2.1.4.min.js* si se encuentra en esa ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Es problema de ubicación relativa del recurso, en este caso del archivo javascript
Por esta parte de

```
<script src="assets/plugins...
```

Esta hace que en cada pagina busque dentro de la "carpeta" de la pagina actual.
Por eso siempre colocamos este tiempo de contenido relativo al raiz del sitio

Quedaria asi, con la barra que indica que busque la carpeta "assets" desde el raiz del sitio web/aplicacion web

```
 <script src="/assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

PD: Deberia estar este archivo en dicha carpeta

Comment: me sigue marcando el mismo error y añadido a este error de mas carpetas cuando coloco la barra

Comment: En que carpeta esta el archivo "jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"? puedes indicarnos eso?